# ef get fields only in base class

Tags: entity-framework, poco, base-class

```
public class baseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


public class ProjectEntity : baseEntity
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNo { get; set; }
}


public class ProcessEntity : baseEntity
{
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
    public int Steps { get; set; }
}

public class DBContext : DbContext
{
    public DBContext() : base("DefaultConnection") 
    {

    }
    public DbSet<baseEntity> BaseEntities { get; set; }

}

DBContext db = new DBContext();
var list = from p in db.BaseEntities select p
```

this will get all fields from baseentity .whatever it is BaseEntity, ProcessEntity or ProjectEntity.

I want to get the fields only in BaseEntity (only ID,Name)，How can I do ?

```
var list = from p in db.BaseEntities select new {p.ID,p.Name}
```

this is not what I want.Because there are a lot of fields in my project. I don't like to write the code like this

```
var list = from p in db.BaseEntities select new {p.ID,p.Name,p.xxx .....................}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
var list = from p in db.BaseEntities.OfType<baseEntity>() select p
```

Yet, keep in mind the actual `Sql` query to be generated depends on your `Inheritance Strategy` (TPT/TPH/TPC).

Answer (score 0):

ofType can finish this job.thank you. But there are more Fields and more Inheritance class will add to this project.

```
var list = from p in db.BaseEntities.OfType<baseEntity>() select p
```

will generate a very complex sql. I try list.toString() to get the sql and copy to the SQL Server Management Studio , the content is more than 8000 lines. How to improve the  performance ?

Comment: `ToString()` will not give you the sql, use something like: http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/EFProf